# Updated Code: Scheme/Racket: Reading my argument as a list

Tags: recursion, scheme, racket

I updated my code, and although I have not arrived at a solution, I am getting there.  This is a homework assignment, so I am not looking for someone to solve it for me.  I want to solve this on my own.  Just wanted to show my progress.

```
(define has-subtarget?(lambda(ls thirdVal sumA sumB)
                    (cond
                      ((and (null? (cdr ls)) (= sumA sumB) (= sumA sumB) (= sumA thirdVal) (> sumA 0) (> sumB 0)))
                      (null? (cdr ls))
                     (else                                  
                       (has-subtarget?(cdr ls) thirdVal (+ (car ls) sumA) sumB)
                       (has-subtarget?(cdr ls) thirdVal sumA (+ (car ls) sumB))
                       (if (= thirdVal 0)
                           (has-subtarget?(cdr ls) (car ls) sumA sumB)
                       ))
                     )
                     #f
                    ))
```

Below is my original code that was giving me an error:

```
"+: contract violation expected: number? given: last argument position: 1st"
```

I figured out that for some reason it is reading my (+ addToA sumA) as a list rather than the value of want to return from the addition in order for my recursive program to work.

Here is how I'm calling my function:

```
(has-subtarget? 0 0 0 0 0 '(1 2 3 4)) 

(define has-subtarget?
  (lambda (addToA addToB thirdSetVal sumA sumB lst)
      (cond
     ((and (and (and (and (null? (cdr'(lst))) (= sumA sumB)) (> 0 sumA)) (> 0 sumB)) (= sumA thirdSetVal)) #t)
     (else
          (has-subtarget? 0 (car'(lst)) thirdSetVal (+ addToA sumA) (+ addToB sumB) (cdr'(lst)))
                    (has-subtarget? (car'(lst)) 0 thirdSetVal (+ addToA sumA) (+ addToB sumB) (cdr'(lst)))

          (if((or(and (= sumA 0) (= sumB 0)) (= thirdSetVal 0)))
             (has-subtarget? 0 0 (car'(lst)) (+addToA sumA) (+ addToB sumB) (cdr'(lst))))

          )))


    )
```

Comment: I'm afraid there are some issues with your code. For example, in the `else` part: you call the recursion twice, but you _discard the results_. You're assuming that `sumA`, `sumB`, `thirdSetVal` have changed their values, but they have not - that's not how functional programming works, you need to use the returned values, the parameters do not change after the recursion returns. Also, you're incorrectly quoting the list:  `(cdr'(lst))` must be written as `(cdr lst)`

Comment: Thank you.  So would (car'(lst)) also be written as (car lst)?

Comment: Of course!. But that's the least of your problems, you need to understand how Scheme programs are written, and why your current attempt won't work, at all. In fact, you'll have to rewrite the code from scratch.

Comment: `(and (and (and (and A B) C) D) E)` is the same like `(and A B C D E)`

Comment: what is the aim of `has-subtarget`? what should it test?

Comment: Ah I see it is kind of a home work: https://www.chegg.com/homework-help/questions-and-answers/write-function-subtarget-takes-list-three-positive-integers-duplicates-possible-0-included-q32622428